# Go mock interface with vendored imports

Tags: go

I'm using the Docker API and pass the `Client` to a function like this:

```
func DoStuffToDocker(ctx context.Context, c *client.Client, ID string) {
    c.ContainerInspect(ctx, ID)
    // do stuff
}
```

I create an interface that defines the functions I use so that I can pass a mock in my tests:

```
type dockerClient interface {
    ContainerInspect(ctx context.Context, containerID string) (types.ContainerJSON, error)
}
```

... and then change the signature of my function to accept the interface instead of the client.

My problem is that the compiler complains that the client doesn't implement the interface. From what I can tell the reason is that the implementation of `ContainerInspect` uses the `golang.org/x/net/context` context which the API has vendored (so the import is actually `github.com/docker/docker/vendor/golang.org/x/net/context`).

How can I create the interface so that the client implements it?

Comment: What version of go are you using?  I thought the difference between `"context"` and `"golang.org/x/net/context"` was handled by the compiler. 
Maybe because it's vendored that's not the case.

Comment: @zak I'm using go 1.10.3, so I guess the vendoring could be it.

Comment: What happens if you temporarily delete / remove the checked in, vendored package `github.com/docker/docker/vendor/golang.org/x/net/context`

Comment: Turns out my docker dependency was too old. I checked [the source on github](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/53683bd8326b988977650337ee43b281d2830076/client/container_inspect.go) and the [latest commit](https://github.com/moby/moby/commit/7d62e40f7e4f3c17d229a7687d6fcca5448de813) to one of the files I depend on actually migrated from `golang.org/x/net/context` to `context`. I updated it, deleted my `vendor` folder, and after running `dep ensure -update` everything is as expected. Thanks for the pointers :)

Comment: Great! really pleased you sorted it :+1: